# Grouping data in google sheets?

Tags: sql, database, recursion, google-sheets

I want to know how I could group the information from google sheets such that I can form groups with 3 team members. I want to be able to copy information of a registrants details (if the number of team members is under 3) and then paste it into the column above such that it can form a team of 3. The sorted list should look something like this.

unsorted array sample

[image: unsorted array sample]

sorted array sample

[image: sorted array sample]

I've tried using some google sheets functions such as VLOOKUP, what java/python APIs would you recommend to solve this problem.

```
"entry": [{
            "id": {
                "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/cokwr"
            },
            "updated": {
                "$t": "2020-07-28T09:58:17.850Z"
            },
            "category": [{
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
            }],
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "Dan"
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "registrantlastname: M, registrantsemailadress: dan@gmail.com, secondmemebersfullname: MatL, secondmembersemail: mal@gmail.com, thirdmembersfullname: Oscar, thirdmembersemailaddress: radio@hotmail.com, teammembers: 3"
            },
            "link": [{
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/cokwr"
            }],
            "gsx$registrantfirstname": {
                "$t": "Dan"
            },
            "gsx$registrantlastname": {
                "$t": "M"
            },
            "gsx$registrantsemailadress": {
                "$t": "dan@gmail.com"
            },
            "gsx$secondmemebersfullname": {
                "$t": "MatL"
            },
            "gsx$secondmembersemail": {
                "$t": "mal@gmail.com"
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersfullname": {
                "$t": "Oscar"
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersemailaddress": {
                "$t": "radio@hotmail.com"
            },
            "gsx$teammembers": {
                "$t": "3"
            }
        }, {
            "id": {
                "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/cpzh4"
            },
            "updated": {
                "$t": "2020-07-28T09:58:17.850Z"
            },
            "category": [{
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
            }],
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "Mariana"
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "registrantlastname: Fake, registrantsemailadress: mari.fake@itesm.ru, secondmemebersfullname: Johnathan, secondmembersemail: jan@gmail.com, teammembers: 2"
            },
            "link": [{
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/cpzh4"
            }],
            "gsx$registrantfirstname": {
                "$t": "Mariana"
            },
            "gsx$registrantlastname": {
                "$t": "Fake"
            },
            "gsx$registrantsemailadress": {
                "$t": "mari.fake@itesm.ru"
            },
            "gsx$secondmemebersfullname": {
                "$t": "Johnathan"
            },
            "gsx$secondmembersemail": {
                "$t": "jan@gmail.com"
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersfullname": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersemailaddress": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$teammembers": {
                "$t": "2"
            }
        }, {
            "id": {
                "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/cre1l"
            },
            "updated": {
                "$t": "2020-07-28T09:58:17.850Z"
            },
            "category": [{
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
            }],
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "Lorem"
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "registrantlastname: Ipsum, registrantsemailadress: lorem@gmail.com, teammembers: 1"
            },
            "link": [{
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/cre1l"
            }],
            "gsx$registrantfirstname": {
                "$t": "Lorem"
            },
            "gsx$registrantlastname": {
                "$t": "Ipsum"
            },
            "gsx$registrantsemailadress": {
                "$t": "lorem@gmail.com"
            },
            "gsx$secondmemebersfullname": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$secondmembersemail": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersfullname": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersemailaddress": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$teammembers": {
                "$t": "1"
            }
        }, {
            "id": {
                "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/chk2m"
            },
            "updated": {
                "$t": "2020-07-28T09:58:17.850Z"
            },
            "category": [{
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
            }],
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "Ki"
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "registrantlastname: C, registrantsemailadress: abc@live.com, teammembers: 1"
            },
            "link": [{
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/chk2m"
            }],
            "gsx$registrantfirstname": {
                "$t": "Ki"
            },
            "gsx$registrantlastname": {
                "$t": "C"
            },
            "gsx$registrantsemailadress": {
                "$t": "abc@live.com"
            },
            "gsx$secondmemebersfullname": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$secondmembersemail": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersfullname": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersemailaddress": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$teammembers": {
                "$t": "1"
            }
        }, {
            "id": {
                "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/ciyn3"
            },
            "updated": {
                "$t": "2020-07-28T09:58:17.850Z"
            },
            "category": [{
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
            }],
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "jane"
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "$t": "registrantlastname: Ong, registrantsemailadress: j.ong@live.com, secondmemebersfullname: john Ong, secondmembersemail: j.ong@live.com, teammembers: 2"
            },
            "link": [{
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sjPsuoIZOJWRLLcJlvZbvKuHnGn6KfaqLLa3rpSXmR0/od6/public/values/ciyn3"
            }],
            "gsx$registrantfirstname": {
                "$t": "jane"
            },
            "gsx$registrantlastname": {
                "$t": "Ong"
            },
            "gsx$registrantsemailadress": {
                "$t": "j.ong@live.com"
            },
            "gsx$secondmemebersfullname": {
                "$t": "john Ong"
            },
            "gsx$secondmembersemail": {
                "$t": "j.ong@live.com"
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersfullname": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$thirdmembersemailaddress": {
                "$t": ""
            },
            "gsx$teammembers": {
                "$t": "2"
            }
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Instead of links,can you please paste the arrays in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem should be for a large dataset like this.

[image: Large dataset]

From here onwards, you can collect all who are in groups of 2 by selecting the filter icon in top right corner view and split them into groups of 1 using VLOOKUP and drag it down to repeat itself. [image]

Finally, combine the 1s together and use HLOOKUP functions to get the correct names and indexes. For the team members just enter values (3,1,1). This will give you the array you want.

[image: Final step, drag down]